# How Can I use nginx X-Accel-Redirect in a ruby cgi script

Tags: ruby, nginx, cgi, x-accel-redirect

I'm using nginx to run a ruby script. I've already set up the nginx config correctly as it works with php-fpm
In php I set

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect, file_path)
```

Is there an equivalent for it in ruby.

I have tried it with

```
cgi = CGI.new
cgi.out( "X-Accel-Redirect"  => new_file)
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Is any any gem that I could include. 
I'm new to ruby. any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Rack application (Rails, Sinatra, Padrino etc.) the same way you used your php-fpm apps (i.e. behind Nginx as a reverse proxy), you should be able to do the same thing you did in PHP:

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = file_path
```